# What is wrong when a for loop cannot be finished in the python console?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Can anyone tell me why this for loop does not work?

```
lst = []
c_lst = []
for i in range(182):
    c_lst.append(df.loc[i, 'LE']
    c_lst = 5 * c_lst
    lst = lst + c_lst
```

I cannot finish the loop (the prompt does not appear again) in the python console and don't see why this wouldn't work.

`df` is a dataframe with 182 rows, 'LE' is one of the columns name. I want to create a list `lst` with every element of the column 'LE' that appears 5 times in `lst`.

Comment: Need this - `np.repeat(df['LE'].values, 5)`?

Comment: Missing parens in line 4 is the likely culprit as @rocketsfallonrocketfalls suggests. But your code may also blow up. Do you really mean to duplicate your result 5x each iteration? `5 * [1]` returns `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, then the next loop you'll have a list 25 long, then 125, then...

Comment: @MichaelDelgado this was a typo. I updated the question now.

Comment: please either leave your question as it was or delete it - with your edit there is no question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find what was wrong. The code should be:

```
lst = []
for i in range(182):
    c_lst = []
    c_lst.append(df.loc[i, 'LE'])
    c_lst = 5 * c_lst
    lst = lst + c_lst
```

This way the for loop can come to an end and the `lst` is like I wanted it to be. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, it was the excessive repetition that was presumably bogging you down before - you were creating a list of length `sum_(i in range(182))(5^(i + 1))`

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thank you! I will delete the question. You are right.

Comment: Cannot delete question, so I leave it with the faults.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a for-loop, consider using array operations with numpy. The [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile) method will repeat the entire `df.LE` vector, which you could then flatten with [`numpy.array.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).

Using a sample dataframe which counts from 0 to 499:

```py
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'LE': np.arange(500)})
```

The array can be repeated 5 times horizontally, then unrolled to get the desired output `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ..., 499, 499, 499, 4999, 499]`:

```py
In [5]: np.tile(df[['LE']], (1, 5)).ravel()
Out[5]: array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 499, 499, 499])
```

The vectorized method is significantly faster:

```
In [11]: %timeit np.tile(df[['LE']], (1, 5)).ravel()
453 µs ± 51.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [12]: %%timeit
    ...: lst = []
    ...: for i in range(len(df)):
    ...:     c_lst = []
    ...:     c_lst.append(df.loc[i, 'LE'])
    ...:     c_lst = 5 * c_lst
    ...:     lst = lst + c_lst
    ...:
4.75 ms ± 57.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Here, the for-loop takes 10x longer. But for a larger array, e.g. one with 10k elements, the difference really appears:

```py
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame({'LE': np.arange(10000)})

In [14]: %timeit np.tile(df[['LE']], (1, 5)).ravel()
623 µs ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [15]: %%timeit
    ...: lst = []
    ...: for i in range(len(df)):
    ...:     c_lst = []
    ...:     c_lst.append(df.loc[i, 'LE'])
    ...:     c_lst = 5 * c_lst
    ...:     lst = lst + c_lst
    ...:
609 ms ± 26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Here the for loop is 1000x slower. I tried this with 1 million elements, but got tired of waiting for the for loop to complete... haha.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be because you have a missing paranthesis `)` at the end of the 4th line and you are trying to write the code in the terminal window?

Comment: This was a typo. Yes, I try to manipulate a dataframe in the python interpreter in the Terminal window.